# LLVM - instrument a function in every loops and pass all local variables to it

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I am using LLVM10. It it probably a simple question: I need to instrument a function call in every loops in C/C++ code and pass all local variables (every local variable accessible in the scope) to it.

For example:

```
void foo() {
    int a; float b = .2;
    for (int a=0; a<10; a++) {
        b = b * 2;
    }
}
```

I need to change it to:

```
    void dummyFunction(int arg1, float arg2) {
    }
    void foo() {
        int a; float b = .2;
        for (int a=0; a<10; a++) {
            dummyFunction(a, b);
            b = b * 2;
        }
    }
```

The signature of the dummyFunction depends on the number of local variables.

Comment: Are you looking for a lambda function with capture? Can you please say why you want exactly this? Perhaps someone can then provide more precise answer.

Comment: I am trying to infer the loop invariants (in C/C++ codes) using Daikon tool. They infer the invariant for every functions not loops and suggest to call a dummy function with all local variables.

I would appreciate if someone have a better solution for loop invariant inference even.

Comment: You're not using `arg1` and `arg2` in your second example. Is this a mistake?

Comment: Also, it reads from your comment like you want to ask something different from what's here. If this is not what you really want to ask I suggest you edit the question.

Comment: What you want isn't too difficult, perhaps a hundred lines of code involving LoopInfo and some liveness analysis. But I suggest that you step back and start by learning LLVM IR, because the language doesn't have either local variables or scopes, and you'll find this problem easier to solve when you're comfortable with the language.

Comment: @kabanus
It is not a mistake. The dummyFunction is required just to be considered as an program point on which the Daikon could infer an invariants. Thanks

Comment: @arnt Thanks for the comment. I have a basic understanding of IR. Would you please suggest some examples or elaborate on what you suggest. Thanks